# How to render list of hundreds of Images using FlatList and JSON data

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-native

Hi I would like to learn how I can map() through this JSON and grab the href of each image and place into a FlatList?

Currently the information I am trying to grab is collection.items.links[0].href and would like to place this href into the Image uri

The problem is I can grab one image easy and place it into a FlatList, but cannot work out how I can grab all of them and render a list of hundreds of images using the FlatList. This is because somehow I need to use map() at this point it seems:

*collection.items* **map()** .*links[0].href*

Thank you in advance!

**Example of Json**

```
{
  "collection": {
    "links": [
      {
        "prompt": "Next",
        "rel": "next",
        "href": "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?media_type=image&q=moon&page=2"
      }
    ],
    "version": "1.0",
    "metadata": {
      "total_hits": 6726
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "render": "image",
            "rel": "preview",
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12235/PIA12235~thumb.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "data": [
          {
            "nasa_id": "PIA12235",
            "secondary_creator": "ISRO/NASA/JPL-Caltech/Brown Univ.",
            "keywords": [
              "Moon",
              "Chandrayaan-1"
            ],
            "date_created": "2009-09-24T18:00:22Z",
            "media_type": "image",
            "title": "Nearside of the Moon",
            "description_508": "Nearside of the Moon",
            "center": "JPL",
            "description": "Nearside of the Moon"
          }
        ],
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12235/collection.json"
      },
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "render": "image",
            "rel": "preview",
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA13517/PIA13517~thumb.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "data": [
          {
            "nasa_id": "PIA13517",
            "secondary_creator": "NASA/GSFC/Arizona State University",
            "keywords": [
              "Moon",
              "Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter LRO"
            ],
            "date_created": "2010-09-10T22:24:40Z",
            "media_type": "image",
            "title": "Color of the Moon",
            "description_508": "Color of the Moon",
            "center": "JPL",
            "description": "Color of the Moon"
          }
        ],
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA13517/collection.json"
      },
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "render": "image",
            "rel": "preview",
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12233/PIA12233~thumb.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "data": [
          {
            "nasa_id": "PIA12233",
            "secondary_creator": "NASA/JPL-Caltech",
            "keywords": [
              "Moon",
              "Chandrayaan-1"
            ],
            "date_created": "2009-09-24T18:00:20Z",
            "media_type": "image",
            "title": "Mapping the Moon, Point by Point",
            "description_508": "Mapping the Moon, Point by Point",
            "center": "JPL",
            "description": "Mapping the Moon, Point by Point"
          }
        ],
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12233/collection.json"
      },
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "render": "image",
            "rel": "preview",
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12228/PIA12228~thumb.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "data": [
          {
            "nasa_id": "PIA12228",
            "secondary_creator": "NASA/JPL-Caltech/USGS",
            "keywords": [
              "Moon",
              "Cassini-Huygens"
            ],
            "date_created": "2009-09-24T18:00:15Z",
            "media_type": "image",
            "title": "Cassini Look at Water on the Moon",
            "description_508": "Cassini Look at Water on the Moon",
            "center": "JPL",
            "description": "Cassini Look at Water on the Moon"
          }
        ],
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12228/collection.json"
      },
```

Also here is my code:

```
export default class ThirdScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: "",
    data: "",
  }

  fetchNasa = () => {
    const {search} = this.state;

    fetch(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${search}&media_type=image`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => this.setState({
      data: result.collection.items[0].links[0].href
    }))

  }




  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return ( 

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={{margin: 5, backgroundColor: 'black', padding: 15}}
          >
          <Image 
            source={{uri: this.state.data}}
            style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
          />  
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }

    render() {
      const {data} = this.state
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: due to memory and other resource constraints, not to mention time constraints, it's impossible to render an infinite list.  Maybe you mean a list of unknown size?

Comment: Correct a list of unknown size :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a function that takes each item of the original array and returns the new item that replaces it. You can use it to transform arrays from one structure to another. For example, you can transform the JSON data in your post from its original, complicated form to simply an array of strings of the HREFs:

```
const data = result.collection.items.map(eachItem => {
    return Array.isArray(eachItem.links) && eachItem.links[0] && eachItem.links[0].href
});
```

Now plug something like that into your `fetchNasa` function so that your `data` variable in state is an array of strings representing HREFs:

```
fetchNasa = () => {
  const {search} = this.state;
  fetch(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${search}&media_type=image`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => this.setState({
      data: result.collection.items.map(eachItem => {
        return Array.isArray(eachItem.links) && eachItem.links[0] && eachItem.links[0].href
      })
    }));
}
```

Finally, `renderItem` should use the item passed to it as an argument in order to return what to render. In fact, `renderItem` is essentially a version of an `Array.map` function: it takes each item of the original data structure and returns some kind of React elements to render:

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return ( 
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={{margin: 5, backgroundColor: 'black', padding: 15}}
      >
      <Image 
        source={{uri: item}}
        style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
      />  
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Because each item in your `this.state.data` array is a string representing an HREF, you can pass that directly into your `<Image>` source prop as the URI.

Comment: Really appreciate the long explanation and learnt a lot from it! Only one problem, I am now getting this error?

Comment: ```JSON Value '0' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString```

Comment: @SwiftyCON Does it indicate a line number? It probably has to do with `return Array.isArray(eachItem) && eachItem[0] && eachItem[0].href`

Comment: @SwiftyCON Ah it's probably supposed to be `Array.isArray(eachItem.links) && eachItem.links[0] && eachItem.links[0].href`. I've edited my answer.